# Is there a better way of getting mutable references to disjoint struct fields?

Tags: rust

I have some Rust code that I find to be pretty smelly. I want to get mutable references from the fields of a struct at the same time, but of course Rust does not allow more than one mutable reference at the same time.

What I have been doing currently is basically making a newtype of a tuple and then pattern matching the two different types out into separate `ref mut` patterns. Not a huge fan of the way this looks in practice.

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self, bar: &mut Bar) {
        bar.bar();
    }
}

struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    fn bar(&mut self) {
        println!("bar")
    }
}

struct FooBar((Foo, Bar));

impl FooBar {
    fn foobar(&mut self) {
        let &mut FooBar((ref mut foo, ref mut bar)) = self;
        foo.foo(bar);
        println!("foobar");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foobar = FooBar((Foo, Bar));
    foobar.foobar();
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=struct%20Foo%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20foo%28%26mut%20self%2C%20bar%3A%20%26mut%20Bar%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar.bar%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Bar%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20bar%28%26mut%20self%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22bar%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20FooBar%28%28Foo%2C%20Bar%29%29%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20FooBar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20foobar%28%26mut%20self%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20%26mut%20FooBar%28%28ref%20mut%20foo%2C%20ref%20mut%20bar%29%29%20%3D%20self%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo.foo%28bar%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22foobar%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20foobar%20%3D%20FooBar%28%28Foo%2C%20Bar%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20foobar.foobar%28%29%3B%0A%7D&version=stable)

Is there a better way I should be doing this? Or perhaps some ideas about general ways to structure the code so that I do not need this newtype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust's borrow analysis natively supports borrowing disjoint fields.

You can use either a tuple-like `struct` or a regular `struct`, and it all just works:

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self, bar: &mut Bar) {
        bar.bar();
    }
}

struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    fn bar(&mut self) {
        println!("bar")
    }
}

struct Tupled(Foo, Bar);

impl Tupled {
    fn foobar(&mut self) {
        self.0.foo(&mut self.1);
    }
}

struct Named {
    foo: Foo,
    bar: Bar,
}

impl Named {
    fn foobar(&mut self) {
        self.foo.foo(&mut self.bar);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tupled = Tupled(Foo, Bar);
    tupled.foobar();

    let mut named = Named{ foo: Foo, bar: Bar };
    named.foobar();
}
```

This compiles and runs [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3534b79d06acc59f6023&version=stable).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to newtype a tuple, you can just create a tuple-struct directly:

```
struct FooBar(Foo, Bar);
```

Then you can write your code pretty concisely as

```
fn foobar(&mut self) {
    self.0.foo(&mut self.1);
    println!("foobar");
}
```

by using tuple indexing instead of a let binding.